# Pooling for 1D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, max-pooling

I am looking for a way to reduce the length of a 1D tensor by applying a pooling operation. How can I do it? If I apply `MaxPool1d`, I get the error `max_pool1d() input tensor must have 2 or 3 dimensions but got 1`.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

A = np.random.rand(768)
m = nn.MaxPool1d(4,4)
A_tensor = torch.from_numpy(A)
output = m(A_tensor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization is fine, you've defined the first two parameters of [`nn.MaxPool1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool1d.html): `kernel_size` and `stride`. For one-dimensional max-pooling both should be integers, *not* *tuple*s.

The issue is with your input, it should be two-dimensional (the batch axis is missing):

```
>>> m = nn.MaxPool1d(4, 4)
>>> A_tensor = torch.rand(1, 768)
```

Then inference will result in:

```
>>> output = m(A_tensor)
>>> output.shape
torch.Size([1, 192])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant the following instead:

```
m = nn.MaxPool1d((4,), 4)
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool1d.html), the arguments are:

> `torch.nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size, stride=None, padding=0, dilation=1, return_indices=False, ceil_mode=False)`

As you can see, it's one `kernel_size`, it's not something like `kernel_size1` `kernel_size2`. Instead it's just only `kernel_size`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I put two numbers to indicate both kernel_size and stride.

Comment: I still get the same error if I add a new set of parenthesis ad you suggested.

Comment: I still get the same error. I get I should convert the numpy array into a 2D tensor, which has one dimension set to one.

Comment: @albus_c Yeah, the `MaxPool1d` requires 2 or 3 dimensional `kernel_size`

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: the solution is to reshape the tensor using `A_tensor.reshape(768,1)`.

Comment: This is incorrect, look at the shape of the resulting tensor: it's empty. The extra dimension should be added *first*, not *last*.